# How to get a license to have an Elo rating in USA

Tags: rating, elo, fide

Which link should I follow to get a license in order to have an Elo rating in the USA?

Comment: For clarification, you are interested in obtaining a [USCF](http://www.uschess.org/) rating?

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: If you obtain a FIDE rating, assuming that's what you are talking about, then it/s valid in every other member nations.

Comment: There is no such thing as "a license in order to have an Elo rating in the USA".

Answer (score -2):

FIDE (the international chess organization) gives Elo ratings, and individual countries recognize them.  There should be no need to have a USA-specific "license".  If FIDE says you have a given Elo rating, that's your Elo rating, worldwide.

Complicating this a bit is the fact that Elo ratings are actually a ratings methodology created by Professor Arpad Elo, which in theory could be used independently of FIDE, but the historical association is so strong as to be able to consider "Elo rating" and "FIDE rating" as functionally synonymous.

Disclaimer:  I've been out of tournament chess for quite a few years.  Something could have changed in the interim.

Comment: *"Elo ratings ... in theory could be used independently of FIDE, but the historical association is so strong as to be able to consider 'Elo rating' and 'FIDE rating' as functionally synonymous."* Both FIDE and the USCF use Elo rating systems. And in fact, Elo's system was originally implemented by the USCF in 1960 (and is still in use in their ratings today), and then adopted by FIDE only in 1970. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system

Comment: Yes, but as of the 10 years or so I was active in tournament chess, it was immediately understood that a reference to an "Elo rating" was a reference to that player's FIDE rating.  A USCF rating would be referred to as one's "USCF rating", or if in the U.S., simply "rating".  Now, even chess software gives a purported "Elo rating" based on analysis of the user's play, so I'm not discounting a shift in common usage.